# How to catch exceptions in FutureTask

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, futuretask

After finding that `FutureTask` running in a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` on Java 1.6 (and from Eclipse) swallows exceptions in the `Runnable.run()` method, I've tried to come up with a way to catch these without adding throw/catch to all my `Runnable` implementations.

The API suggests that overriding `FutureTask.setException()` should help in this:

> Causes this future to report an ExecutionException  with the given throwable as its cause, unless this Future has already been set or has been cancelled. This method is invoked internally by the run method upon failure of the computation.

However this method doesn't seem to be called (running with the debugger shows the exception is caught by `FutureTask`, but `setException` isn't called). I've written the following program to reproduce my problem:

```
public class RunTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFutureTask t = new MyFutureTask(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unchecked exception");

            }
        });

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        service.submit(t);
    }
}

public class MyFutureTask extends FutureTask<Object> {

    public MyFutureTask(Runnable r) {
        super(r, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setException(Throwable t) {
        super.setException(t);
        System.out.println("Exception: " + t);
    }
}
```

My main question is: How can I catch Exceptions thrown in a FutureTask? Why doesn't `setException` get called?

Also I would like to know why the `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` mechanism  isn't used by `FutureTask`, is there any reason for this?

Comment: `setException` is well used. I copied-pasted your code and it works.
You may also want to try the try-catch of `ExecutionException` when calling the `get()` method on the task.

Comment: Wrong way of using the Callable/Future combo. The future.get() method provides you the exception wrapped in a ExecutionException.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`setException` probably isn't made for overriding, but is provided to let you set the result to an exception, should the need arise. What you want to do is override the `done()` method and try to get the result:

```
public class MyFutureTask extends FutureTask<Object> {

    public MyFutureTask(Runnable r) {
        super(r, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            if (!isCancelled()) get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // Exception occurred, deal with it
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getCause());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Shouldn't happen, we're invoked when computation is finished
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how we can pull the status code from ExecutionException object?

Comment: @Min2 if you want the exception that caused the `ExecutionException`, you can use `getCause()` like I do in the println statement.

Comment: @gustafc I tried the same way but using e.getCause() , I am able to get the Throwable object and error message but I need to retrieve networkResponse object in which status code is present.

Comment: @Min2 just downcast it to the correct type (preferably after an `instanceof` check)

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried using an [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)?

- You need to implement the [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) interface.
- To set an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` for pool threads, provide a [`ThreadFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) in the `Executor.newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory)` call.
- You can set the UncaughtExceptionHandler for the created thread via `setUncaughtExceptionHandler(Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler eh)`

Submit the tasks with [`ExecutorService.execute`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), because only exceptions thrown from tasks submitted with `execute` make it to the uncaught exception handler. For Tasks submitted with [`ExecutorService.submit`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) any thrown exception is considered to be part of the task's return value. If a task submitted with submit terminates with an exception, it is rethrown when calling [`Future.get`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), wrapped in an `ExecutionException`

Comment: Good catch! I was using `ExecutorService.submit` by mistake.

Answer (score 9):

A much better solution:
[Java FutureTask completion check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776908/java-futuretask-completion-check)

When you call `futureTask.get()` to retrieve the result of the computation it will throw an exception (ExecutionException) if the underlying `Runnable`/`Callable` threw an exception.

`ExecutionException.getCause()` will return the exception that the `Runnable`/`Callable` threw.

It will also throw a different exception if the `Runnable`/`Callable` was canceled.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked at the source code of `FutureTask` and could not find where `setException` is being called.
There is an `innerSetException` method from `FutureTask.Sync` (inner class of `FutureTask`) that is being called in case of an `Throwable` being thrown by the run method. This method is also being called in `setException`.
So it seams like the javadoc is not correct (or very hard to understand...).

Comment: After looking some more at the terribly slow sun bugs database: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6464365
Apparantly it is known since 2006 and still not fixed (eventhough it is stated as fixed)

Comment: @Thirler - the bug report clearly says that it is fixed **in Java 7**.

Answer (score 0):

There are three standard ways and one improvised way. 
 1. use UncaughtExceptionHandler, set the UncaughtExceptionHandler for the created thread as

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable ex) {..}}
```

*But the limitation is it catches the exception thrown by thread but in case of future task, it is swallowed.
 2. use `afterExecute` after making a custom threadpoolexecutor with hook that has been provided specially for this purpose. Looking through the code of ThreadpoolExecutor, via submit > execute (there is a workQueue, `workQueue.offer`), the tasks are added to the work queue

```
   final void runWorker(Worker arg0) {
  Thread arg1 = Thread.currentThread();
  Runnable arg2 = arg0.firstTask;
  ..
     while(arg2 != null || (arg2 = this.**getTask()**) != null) {
        arg0.lock();
        ..
        try {
           this.beforeExecute(arg1, arg2);
           Object arg4 = null;
           try {
              arg2.run();
           } catch (RuntimeException arg27) {
             ..
           } finally {
              this.**afterExecute**(arg2, (Throwable)arg4);
           }

  }

getTask() {..
 this.workQueue.**poll**();
..}
```

3. Then, the third is using simple try catch inside the call method but you can not catch the exception outside here.
4. The workaround is calling all the call methods from a call method of a TaskFactory, a factory that releases callables.