# Java: Logging FutureTask exceptions

Tags: java, exception, java.util.concurrent, futuretask

I've got an application which regularly submits tasks to be executed in a dedicated thread. Those tasks are `FutureTask<V>` and the thread is no more than an infinite loop which executes the jobs as they get into a queue, going to sleep if empty.

Sometimes I need to wait for the result of a computation, so I call FutureTask's get() method, which will also throw an exception if something bad happened. But there are cases where I don't care what the result was, if any, but I need to know (log, printStackTrace() or whatever...) if there was some kind of failure during the task execution.

Is there any way I could achieve this without having to wait on a get() that I don't need?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**: Calling get() on the runner thread after executing the task seemed to be the only way to catch the exception if no one else would wait for the result.

Another solution would be extending FutureTask class to provide a method which, via java reflection, exposes sync.exception private field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, there is a simple solution.  Modify your dedicated task-runner thread to call `Future.get()` after running each task, and catch and log the `ExecutionException` (if any).

Note that calling `get` in the task-runner thread after running the task is guaranteed not to block.

(Uncaught exception handlers won't help because any exception and error thrown by the `run()` method of the future's wrapped `Runnable will be caught by`FutureTask.run()`.)

Comment: I can't find this getException() method on Future or FutureTask. Am I missing something? Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Check Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler

Comment: could you add more information about this? I tried to set an UncaughtExceptionHandler on the runner thread, but nothing changed, as I think those exceptions are not ungaught, but instead managed by FutureTask and not exposed until get() method is called. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use 'setException' to report the failure from your task. It will make get() report an ExecutionException.  See this as well:

[How to catch exceptions in FutureTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555302/how-to-catch-exceptions-in-futuretask)

Comment: calling get() is what I want to avoid ;-) I sometimes submit long running tasks to save information on a database... On this cases I don't want to be blocked waiting on a get() but I would like to see possible exceptions logged somewhere. Thanks

Comment: why don't you then just catch exceptions in your thread and log them?

Comment: because FutureTask's run method just doesn't throw exceptions, so even if I put it inside a try-catch block nothing would be logged.

Comment: But you can catch them in your Runnable.run() that you provide for the FutureTask, can't you?

Comment: Well, yes, I could catch them inside my Callables, but I was hoping there was a simpler way to handle this, without requiring me to modify all my predefined job classes and also to be able to log them even if I forget to add the try-catch block to a job.

Comment: OK, I see. If you check the link I provided, the user there tries to log in the overridden setException. Only according to the last response, that only works since Java 7, due to a Java bug.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to override setException() to see if exceptions could be logged there but no luck. Unfortunately, I can't move to java 7 yet.

Answer (score 0):

A [CompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html) might be a possibility here.  Using one of those will allow you to call `get()` on the `Future`s once they are definitely finished.  Alternatively, the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) libraries have ways to add a listener to a `Future` or `FutureTask` to execute when the task is complete (the `ListenableFuture` and its related objects).

Answer (score 0):

You can also check an example I wrote for [Futuretask](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/futuretask)