# Java FutureTask completion check

Tags: java, futuretask

I have checked Oracle Java API, which gives some info that [FutureTask.isDone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#isDone%28%29)

but I need to check whether the task has completed or terminated with any error.
isDone() method will return even if it completes/terminates. But I need to know whether it's completed or terminated due to some problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the `FutureTask` is done, call [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get()) afterwards (can be without any timeout, it should return immediately). It will either return some result or throw:

> `ExecutionException` - if the computation threw an exception

`ExecutionException.getCause()` will return the exception thrown from your task.

Comment: You can call `get()` even if `FutureTask` is not yet done; in this case `get()` waits for completion.

Answer (score 0):

Why not call [FutureTask.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#get%28%29) ?

This will return the result or throw an exception containing the exception originally thrown/caught. If the task hasn't complete dit will block, and you have the option to provide a timeout.

I would *normally* expect clients simply to call `get()` on each `FutureTask` in turn once created, rather than poll `isDone()`.

Answer (score 0):

When `isDone()` return true you would like to get result by calling `get()` method to check the result of execution. `get()` operation can throw `ExecutionException`, which consist of cause, where you can find a problem.

Comment: You can call `get()` even if `isDone()` is yet false; in this case `get()` waits for completion.